# Warning: failed loading '/etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo', skipping. ,Last metadata expiration check: ... が多くのコマンドで表示される

Tags: centos, vscode, dnf

[CentOs8に「VScode」をインストールする手順 -mebee](https://mebee.info/2020/04/07/post-8797/)

の記事を参考に vscode を CentOS(8) にインストールしようとしたところ、インストールもできず、以降、多くのコマンド(dnf info ~ など)で最初に

```
Warning: failed loading '/etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo', skipping.
Last metadata expiration check: x:xx:xx ago on Fri x Oct 2020 xx:xx:xx AM UTC.
```

と表示されるようになってしまいました。
表示を止めるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

**打ち込んだコード**

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo

[code]
name=Visual Studio Code
baseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
    
sudo dnf install code
```

**環境**
・仮想環境 VirtualBox (ホスト環境：Windows10)

**ちなみに**
なぜ vscode はインストールできなかったのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

表示されているワーニングは作成したリポジトリの定義ファイルに何らかのフォーマットエラーがあるのが原因だと思われます。
質問に貼られたコードを見る限りでは問題なさそうなのですが、一度削除した後に改めて作り直してみるとどうなるでしょうか？

行っている内容は参照された記事と最終的には同じですが、VSCode のサイトにワンライナーで登録する方法も載っているので紹介しておきます。

[Visual Studio Code on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "[code]\nname=Visual Studio Code\nbaseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo'
```